# Descobrir se App foi encerrado

Tags: android

Oi, sou iniciante em android e estou desenvolvendo um app. Eu consigo descobrir se a minha activity foi fechada através do método onStop utilizando isFinishing() e isDestroyed() e isso caiu muito bem. Mas eu gostaria de saber como descobrir se o App foi fechado manualmente pelo usuário pois quando eu fecho o meu app o método onStop onde coloquei a verificação não é acionado. O mesmo ocorre quando o meu app fecha porque sofreu algum erro (Ex: o app parou de funcionar). Eu preciso desse controle porque existe uma fila no meu aplicativo e os usuários que estão na fila eu salvo no firebase. Mas se o usuário fecha o app manualmente ou o app fecha por erro eu não estou conseguindo fazer o tratamento para remover ele do firebase. O que eu devo fazer? Esse aqui é o método que fiz no onStop, mas só funciona quando a activity é encerrada.

```
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
if (ChatPrivadoActivity.this.isFinishing() || ChatPrivadoActivity.this.isDestroyed()){           

        Toast.makeText(this,
                "onStop-fechou o app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
        finish();            
}
```

}

Comment: Que eu saiba não é possível receber informação quando o aplicativo é forçado pelo usuário a parar, quando o celular precisa de memória, ou quando crasha. Mas pra amenizar você pode enviar informação quando o aplicativo está indo pra primeiro e/ou segundo plano. Talvez esse link te dê uma luz: [ProcessLifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner) e este que mostra um exemplo [Exemplo em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54684819/10526030)

Comment: Muito obrigada, eu vou olhar o link! Acho que nesse caso eu irei adicionar um tempo máximo para que o usuário fique na fila, dessa forma, mesmo que ele tenha encerrado o aplicativo manualmente ou ele tenha sofrido algum erro o usuário será liberado da fila.